# Glade 3.20 seems to ignore `GLADE_CATALOG_PATH`

Tags: environment-variables, glade

I have created a catalog with a custom widget and a custom group. If I set the `GLADE_CATALOG_PATH` variable and launch glade, the group and the widget are not shown. I have used both relative and absolute paths.

Copying the catalog over to the path returned by `pkg-config --variable=catalogdir gladeui-2.0`, however, works as expected.

Is Glade ignoring the environment variable?

And what about `GLADE_MODULE_PATH`?

Comment: How did you set the variable?

Comment: The same way I used to do with quickly: GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=<path_to_catalog_folder> glade

Comment: I have just realised that Glade 3.20 allows you to add search paths from within the UI itself. However, it would be interesting to know if this means that the variable is now ignored, as the documentation would then be misleading.

Comment: Stating a variable that way, i.e. as part of the command for launching the program, makes the variable present only in the launched process. Possibly glade forks additional processes... You may want to set the variable persistently in `/etc/environment` (and relogin).

Comment: I did `export GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=...`, but the result was the same. I'd like to avoid altering files that require sudo as the whole point of me using the GLADE_CATALOG_PATH is to be able to define new widget in the project folder. Furthermore, it used to work with older versions of Glade (I think back in 2012 it was 3.8 for gtk2 and 3.10 for gtk3).

Comment: What are your system module search paths reported by `pkg-config`? I don't seem to have any `glade*.pc` files installed on my ubuntu 18.04 (but I do have glade installed).

Answer (score 0):

At least for my version of `glade`, the correct environment variables appear to be

- `GLADE_CATALOG_SEARCH_PATH`
- `GLADE_MODULE_SEARCH_PATH`

(note that additional `_SEARCH_`). See [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gladeui/stable/catalogintro.html) for the reference. This works for me with glade 3.22.1.